# How can I count how many characters are in the array?

Tags: c

In this code the user needs to put a character and the array will save that.

The thing is, I need to identify and show it on screen the characters that are duplicated and the number.

For example: a b c a a c c d e e

a - 3
b - 1
c - 3
d - 1
e - 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define L 5
#define C 5

int main() {
    char M[L][C], c;
    int repetiçoes[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)         //LINHAS
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {   //COLUNAS
            printf("Digite a letra desejada M[%i][%i]\n", i, j);
            scanf_s("%c", &M[i][j]);
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
        }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {       //LINHAS
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++)     //COLUNAS
            printf(" %c  ", M[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have used `scanf_s()` incorrectly, because it requires a **size** argument: *"Unlike `scanf` and `wscanf`, `scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type `c`, `C`, `s`, `S`, or string control sets that are enclosed in `[]`. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable."* Microsoft's `scanf_s` is **not** a direct replacement for `scanf`, please take note of compiler warnings.

Comment: ... also please do not mix input methods `scanf_s()` and the `getchar()` kluge. Stick to one method: the `scanf` function family provides a way to filter leading whitespace (where it is not done automatically), in this case by adding a space before `"%c"` to be `" %c"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but it only modifies your code slightly. It checks each lower case letter. You can extend this to check the whole char set.

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            if (M[i][j] == c) count++;
        }
    }
    if (count != 0) printf("%c - %d\n", c, count);
}
```